# $\int_{0}^{1} (x-1)\sqrt{1-x} dx$ without Parts etc..

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

Evaluate:

$$\int_{0}^{1} (x-1)\sqrt{1-x} dx$$

**Without the use of integration by parts**

(1) My initial thought is, can we use *series* for either one of these?

Can we find a series (about x=0) for $\sqrt{1-x}$?

It seems hard, so another tactic:

$$I = \int_{0}^{1} (x-1)\sqrt{1-x} dx$$

$$I = \int_{0}^{1} (x)\sqrt{x} dx$$

That doesnt help either.

So how can this be done?

Comment: Why series approach?

Comment: $$(x)\sqrt{x}=x^{3/2}$$

Answer (score 6):

$$\int_{0}^{1}(x-1)\sqrt{1-x}\,dx = -\int_{0}^{1}(1-x)^{\frac{3}{2}}\,dx = -\int_{0}^{1} x^{\frac{3}{2}}\,dx = \color{red}{-\frac{2}{5}}.$$

Comment: Wow, I must be high today, to not recognize that, jeez. Thanks once again Jack

Comment: @alexjo: the first integrand function is negative on $(0,1)$, so the answer is a negative number, there is nothing wrong.

Answer (score 4):

$$
u = 1-x
$$
Then you have
$$
-\int -u\sqrt{u}du
$$

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

- $\left(x-1\right)\cdot\sqrt{1-x} = -\left(1-x\right)\cdot\sqrt{1-x}$
- Substitute $1-x$